# How to auto-backup Access Database

Tags: vba, ms-access, database-backups

[image: ACCESS VBA]I want to autoback up my access database with the below code and it didn't work for me. I got an error "cannot find the input table or query "WinAutoBackup" Please view the picture. Also, did I use CurrentProject correctly?

```
[Function fMakeBackup() As Boolean

Dim Source As String
Dim Target As String
Dim retval As Integer

On Error GoTo sysBackup_Err

Source = CurrentDb.name

Target = "CurrentProject.path\backups\" 
Target = Target & Format(Now, "yyyymmdd-hhnn") & ".accdb" 

If DateDiff("d", DLookup("\[BackupDate\]", "WinAutoBackup", "\[BckID\] 
=1"), Date) = 3 Then

retval = 0
Dim objFSO As Object
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
retval = objFSO.CopyFile(Source, Target, True)
Set objFSO = Nothing

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
   DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE WinAutoBackup SET WinAutoBackup.BackupDate = 
Date();"
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

MsgBox "Backup successfull. Next auto backup in 3 days"

Else
Exit Function
End If

sysBackup_Exit:
Exit Function

sysBackup_Err:
MsgBox Err.Description, , "sysBackup()"
Resume sysBackup_Exit
End Function][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with including:

```
Option Explicit
```

at the top of the module.

Then try with:

```vb
Function fMakeBackup() As Boolean

    Dim objFSO As Object

    Dim Source As String
    Dim Target As String
    Dim retval As Integer

    ' Disable error handling during development.
    ' On Error GoTo sysBackup_Err

    Source = CurrentDb.Name

    ' Adjust if if backup folder is not \backups\.
    Target = CurrentProject.Path & "\backups\" 
    Target = Target & Format(Now, "yyyymmdd-hhnn") & ".accdb" 

    ' To run every time, use this line in plade of If DateDiff ...:
    ' If True Then
    If DateDiff("d", DLookup("[BackupDate]", "[WinAutoBackup]", "[BckID] = 1"), Date) >= 3 Then  

        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        retval = objFSO.CopyFile(Source, Target, True)
        Set objFSO = Nothing

        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
            DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE WinAutoBackup SET WinAutoBackup.BackupDate = Date() WHERE [BckID] = 1;"
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True

        MsgBox "Backup successful. Next auto backup in 3 days."
    End If

sysBackup_Exit:
    Exit Function

sysBackup_Err:
    MsgBox Err.Description, , "sysBackup()"
    Resume sysBackup_Exit

End Function
```

Comment: OK, I tried it, I guess I have to wait three days to see if it is working

Comment: It sitll not working.  I ahve posted a picture of my VBA code

Comment: Sorry, it is not creating a back-up file.  The directory still only has the actual database file, no back-up file

Comment: It runs fine here. The backup is created in the `\backups` folder.

Comment: Right now, the database is in the directory Z:\Database\Test backup     The obly file in this directory is Protocol Databse.accdb   There are no other files or folders in this directory.  I don't see backups

Comment: Additionally, how am I able to test this without waiting the 3 days?  Is everythign ok in my picture?  Did I insert it correctly?

Comment: If you wish to place the backup in another folder, adjust `Target`. To run every time when called, replace the `If DateDiff ...` as shown in the edited answer.

Comment: Are you still getting an error mentioning "WinAutoBackup"? Do you have a table called "WinAutoBackup" in your Access database? That's what this requires.

Comment: Can you see the place in the code where you change the backups from 3 days to 1 day? hint: it has the number `3` and a bunch of date arithmetic code in it